# C Calculator Error in scanf_s and printf with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, runtime-error, calc

My calculator application I'm trying to make isn't working properly when run. It comes up with a weird message box (see below).

[image: error]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int Pre;
float v1;
float v2;
char op;

printf("Enter precision: ");
scanf_s("%f", &Pre);

if (Pre < 0)
{
    printf("Error: negative precision\n");
    return 0;
}

printf("Enter expression: ");
scanf_s("%f %c %f", &v1, &op, &v2);

if (op == '+')
{
    printf("%f %c %f\n", v1, op, v2);
    return 0;
}


return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `scanf_s` to read data into a `char *` or `wchar_t *`, you must specify the size of the buffer that is accepting the input.

```
scanf_s("%f %c %f", &v1, &op, 1, &v2);
```

Source: [MSDN on scanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

(Note: `scanf_s` is an optional extension to the Standard C library described in C.11 Annex K.3.5.3.4.)

---

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) points out that `"%f"` is the incorrect format specifier for `&Pre`, since `Pre` is an `int`, and `"%f"` indicates the argument will be a pointer to `float`. Use `"%d"` to indicate the argument is a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Also, `%f` is for reading a float. `scanf_s("%f", &Pre)` isn't going to work. Use `%d` for an int.